# How to properly make D3 event listener?

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, listener

I have code that draws a bunch of hexagons but I need them to appear white and do some other stuff when I mouse over them. Why isn't the event listener working and what do I need to do to it?http://jsfiddle.net/rewBr/

```
var elementTags = ["Google", 4, "Wikipedia", "Yahoo!", "Cindy"];
var _s32 = (Math.sqrt(3)/2);
var A = 75;

var svgContainer = d3.select("body") //create container
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000);
var xDiff = [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400];
var yDiff = [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200];
```

`for (index = 0; index < elementTags.length; index++) {
    var pointData = [
        [A+xDiff[index], 0+yDiff[index]],
        [A/2+xDiff[index], (A*_s32)+yDiff[index]],
        [-A/2+xDiff[index], (A*_s32)+yDiff[index]],
        [-A+xDiff[index], 0+yDiff[index]],
        [-A/2+xDiff[index], -(A*_s32)+yDiff[index]],
        [A/2+xDiff[index], -(A*_s32)+yDiff[index]],
        [A+xDiff[index], 0+yDiff[index]]];`

```
    var hexMouseOver = function(){
        console.log(this);
        this.style("fill", "white");
    }

var enterElements = svgContainer.selectAll("path.area") //draw element
    .data([pointData]).enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", "#1D85E0")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line())
    .style("shape-rendering", "auto")
    .on("mouseover", hexMouseOver);
```

}
    `var addText = svgContainer.selectAll("text").data(elementTags).enter().append("text");`

```
var textElements = addText
            .attr("x", function(d, i){
                return xDiff[i];})
            .attr("y", function(d, i){
                return yDiff[i];})
            .attr("font-family", "Arial Black")
            .attr("font-size", "20px")
            .attr("fill", "1A2E40")
            //.attr("font-variant", "small-caps")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d, i){return d;});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select the 'this' element with d3 first:

```
.on("mouseover", function(){
    console.log(this);
    console.log(d3.select(this));
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rewBr/3/

Comment: The handler function doesn't seem to be passed the `MouseEvent` object. Is there a way of getting this, other than `window.event`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with MouseEvent? Have you tried using d3.event or d3.mouse instead?